# Get an inputs component props onBlur

Tags: reactjs, jsx, formsy-react

Is it possible to get the props of an input with the `onBlur` event?

With `event.target.value` I get the value of my input.

Is it possible to get the `props` of the component a similar way?

Comment: Input `props` or `component` props?

Comment: Component props. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxzj3sh3/1/):

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    onBlur: function (e) {
        console.log(this.props);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <input onBlur={this.onBlur} />
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

Or if you receive function from parent as a property, you should bind it to the components context.

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/7fy6s9y2/3/):

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <input onBlur={this.props.onBlur.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        );
    },
});

function onBlur(e) {
    console.log(this.props);
    console.log(e);
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello onBlur={onBlur} name="World" />,
    document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved it.

Comment: Great to help you!